# Reset Page Number in Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

It`s possible to reset the page number in Ireport when I want?

For sample, I receive one parameter maxPage, so when my pageNumber reach this value, I need to back to 1 and start to auto increment again

Comment: yes, it is possible. you can use your own variable

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo - set pageNumber to $P{pageNumber} % $P{maxPage}